# Render (export) entire document as image

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, xetex, lyx, parcolumns

### Background

Using LyX to create a document and xetex to leverage a TrueType font. The entire text is within a minipage. Ultimately, I'm trying to produce the following output (no white page background, single image, captured from OpenOffice):

[image]

### Problem - Update #1

Adding `tolerance` and `emergencystretch` produces:

[image]

### Preamble

The document preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}% provides font selecting commands
\usepackage{xunicode}% provides unicode character macros
\usepackage{xltxtra} % provides some fixes/extras
\setmainfont{Franklin Gothic Book}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6cm}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
```

### Idea - Update #2

The program `pdfcrop` can be used to remove all the extra whitespace in the margins.

### Related Links - Update #3

- http://rene.bz/convert-multi-page-pdf-single-image/
- http://linuxers.org/quick-tips/convert-pdf-file-single-image-using-imagemagick

### Question

How can you render a document as a single image (or as one very, very long page), ignoring any pagination, in a justified (newspaper-style) column format?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) Why do you supress hyphenation (all newspapers hyphenate, it's _very ugly_ non-hyphenated like the OOO image you show). 2) Your package combination seems to disable ligature for `--` to become one long dash. I guess that the only lines of the preable you need are `fontspec` and `\setmainfont`. 3) Then just putting `\setlength{\paperheight}{100in}\setlength{\textheight}{96in}` in the preamble should be enough. 4) Using `\usepackage{microtype}` you can get slightly better-looking result.

Comment: Can you use the `geometry` package to force the text shape you need? That may allow one very long page, which wouldn't print nicely but could be captured from the pdf as the image you want.

Comment: @DaveJarvis How long is the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really can't understand why you don't want hyphenation. Setting `\tolerance=1` is quite dubious. Remove `HyphenChar=None` if you want to switch hyphenation on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=\maxdimen,paperwidth=6.2cm,margin=0.1cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,HyphenChar=None]{Franklin Gothic Book}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % mock text

\begin{document}
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm. `Package xkevyal Error: 'TeX' undefined in families 'Ligatures'.`

Comment: @DaveJarvis You have surely an outdated version of fontspec. Use `Mapping=tex-text` instead of `Ligatures=TeX`, but it's better to upgrade your TeX distribution.